# How to make query parameters required for complex type in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller with the following action:

```
public class MyController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri] int param1, [FromUri] int param2 = 2)
    {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

In this case, if I do a request with http://localhost/myapi/My/Something?param=1 then everything is OK, param1 is required and param2 gets its default value. If I do http://localhost/myapi/My/Something I get "No HTTP resource was found that match the request URI" which is also OK.

But then if I change my method signature to

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri] RequestParames request)
```

where

```
public class RequestParames
{
    public int Param1 {get; set;}
    public int Param2 {get; set;} = 2;
}
```

In this case, WebAPI can't determine which of my complex type properties are required and which are optional, all become optional. So if I request http://localhost/myapi/My/Something I don't get any error which is bad as my internal code expects it to be provided.

So the question is if there is some way to mark my complex type properties to be required?

Comment: The [FromBody] attribute is good for this, but obviously, it'll be in the request body rather than the url.

Comment: Try changing the Action method signature to `public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri] RequestParames request)`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this with RequiredAttribute and ModelState check inside my custom ActionFilterAttribute.

```
public class RequestParames
{
    [Required]
    public int? Param1 {get; set;}
    public int Param2 {get; set;} = 2;
}

internal class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Overrides of ActionFilterAttribute

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;
        if(!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
     }

     #endregion
}

public class MyController
{
    [ValidateModel]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri] RequestParames request)
    {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to write code for validation and then return 404 error.

**RequestParames Class**

```
public class RequestParames
{
    public int? param1 {get; set;}
    public int param2 {get; set;} = 2;
}
```

**Action Method Validation**

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri] RequestParames request) {
  if(request == null || request.param1 == null) { 
     return NotFound();
  }
}
```